2013 Ram 1500 right rear break light and turn signal out | truck shakes when going 60MPH+
I have a 2013 Ram 1500 SLT v8 4.7L 2wd truck.
The issue that started everything was the radiator exploding under heavy load.
Currently, we have fixed the radiator and the thermostat. Completely replacing both to brand new.
The only issues we face now are the rear right brake light and turn signal being out as well as the truck shaking going over 60 MPH.
The rear right brake light and turn signal:
The normal light works when the headlights are on. The only issue is when pressing breaks that light does not light up, and the turn signal does not work.
On the dash, the turn signal flashes faster when using the right-hand one and there is a warning about the light being out.
With a quick visual inspection, the bulb seems to be in good shape but I have not gotten the chance to take the cover off to check since I don't have access to the truck for long. I am worried it is not the bulb, but I can't seem to find the correct fuse to check. What steps should I take to figure out the issue if it's not the bulb?
And the break lights just don't work on that side but it lights up when normal headlights are on.
Truck Shaking
The truck violently shakes when going above 60MPH and I am struggling to believe it's the tires that need to be balanced because it was fine before the incident. What else could I check before I go to a tire shop?
The steering wheel, seats, and floorboards are shaking. It's practically the entire truck.
All information is helpful I appreciate it. Thank you.

Have you checked that all of the wheels are bolted on tight?  Are you saying that the shaking started after the issue with the radiator?  Did you replace the radiator?

@HandyHowie Yes the shaking and the taillight started after the radiator issue. Yes, the radiator and thermostat have been replaced. I do need to check the lug nuts but visually it seems fine.
